# How can I set dojo content tab title with space?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dojo, dijit.layout

I am using Dojo 1.7.1 for my web application for UI and using content tab as a primary way to display information. I generate these content tab dynamically as and when required using ajax calls.

For content tabs, I am facing an issue to have space in content tab title. For example, I want to display tab title as "View Client Details" but it doesn't work with space or  . I'm forced to show it as "ViewClientDetails" which is certainly not good and very limiting on User Interface side.

I have searched at dojo forums and found very little docs on this. How can I set dojo content tab title with space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data-dojo-props="title: 'View Client Details'"
```

should work.